# Metric space whose bounded subsets are totally bounded

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, terminology

Is there a name for a metric space in which any bounded subset is totally bounded, or equivalently, in which any bounded sequence contains a Cauchy subsequence?

I have seen the name Bolzano-Weierstraß property when the subsequence is *convergent*, which in the case of *complete* metric spaces is equivalent to the property I am interested in. Does anyone knows other terminologies in the complete case and/or some terminology in the noncomplete case?

Comment: it is equivalent to the completion enjoying Bolzano-Weierstraß property, right?

Answer (score 6):

**Proper space** is the a complete space such that any bounded subset is totally bounded,

- or equivalently, in which any bounded sequence contains a converging subsequence,
- or equivalently, any bounded closed set is compact,
- or equivalently, the distance function from one (and therefore any) point is proper; the latter means that invese image of any compact set is compact.

For noncomplete space you may say **space with proper completion**, or you may call it **preproper space** by analogy with precompact.

Answer (score 3):

In Functional Analysis such spaces are called *Fréchet-Montel* spaces because of Montel's theorem that closed and bounded subsets of the space $H(\Omega)$ of holomorphic functions on an open subset of $\mathbb C$ are compact (this is one of the main ingredients in Riemann's mapping theorem).

Comment: Does it assume completeness?

Comment: Horváth in his book *Topological Vector Spaces and Distributions* calls a locally convex space *semi-Montel* if every bounded set is relatively compact. This implies that closed bounded sets are complete and in the metrizable case completeness. For a locally convex *Montel space* one requires additionally barreledness. 
In the metrizable case this is automatic by Baire's theorem.